# pfsense WAN IP using a modem in bridge mode and PPPoE

Tags: pfsense, wan

My WAN interface on pfsense which is configured using PPPoE shows an IP address of 100.64... though my real external IP address is 213.137...
What is the IP shown in the WAN interface widget? where is it taken from?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my ISP is using CGNAT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) - meaning there is another NAT on the way - the IP I see is an intermediate IP and not the WAN IP. It prevents me from using port forwarding.
According to my ISP, they cannot disable it, and I should purchase a static IP.